# C# Windows Form Application Update Query for Foreign Keys VS2010

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2010, foreign-keys

Guys i need help need to update my Curriculum Name.
Table1: Curricuculum
   -CurriculumID ( PK, Auto_Increment )
   -Curriculum Name
Table2: Grade Level
   -GradeLevelID( PK, Auto_Increment )
   -GradeLevel
   -CurriculumID( Foreign Key connected to Curriculum table)

Result:

GradeLevel | Curriculum Name
  ````````````Grade1```````````K-12`````````
Update to

`````````````Grade2``````````K-11

problem is whenever i press the update button, it wont update because my Update Query wont work. here are my codes. PLEASE HELP~

```
private void btnGLEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //update
                SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection();
                scon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=HSPAEnrollmentSytem;Integrated Security=True";
                //scon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=D630 ;Initial Catalog=NLEDB; User ID=approj1; Password=approj1";
                scon.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE GradeLevel set GradeLevel = @GradeLevel, CurriculumID = @CurriculumID where GradeLevelID = '" + txtGradeLevelID.Text + "'", scon);



                //cmd.Parameters.Add("@GradeLevel", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtGradeLevel.Text.Trim();
                //cmd.Parameters.Add("@CurriculumID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GradeLevel", txtGradeLevel.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurriculumID", comboBox1.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("update");
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean it won't work? Is it raising an exception? What error message are you getting?

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean? are you getting an exception? from the looks of it you're ignoring any sql exceptions that occur, rather than throwing them or at least doing a `Debug.Write(ex.StackTrace)` - have you tried to debug at all?

Comment: you guys know the UPDATE Query for Foreign key? i just can't update it. Because it should update the Curriculum Name not the Curriculum ID. like its not connecting each other

Comment: `it should update the Curriculum Name not the Curriculum ID` you ARE updating the curriculum ID. Nothing in your query is trying to update the curriculum name.What do you want to update the name with? What's supposed to have after the update?

Comment: @JoshPart i tried using CurriculumID in my query because i thought it will automatically connect with Curriculum name. hmm example: Grade 1, Curriculum k-12(kindergarden-grade 12) then Update to Grade 2, Curriculum K-13

Comment: I would be useful if you add to your question some sample data and the desired result after the update...

Answer (score 0):

You have nothing referencing your column `Curriculum Name` in your update statement:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE GradeLevel set GradeLevel = @GradeLevel, CurriculumID = @CurriculumID where GradeLevelID = '" + txtGradeLevelID.Text + "'", scon);
```

what do you expect the `Curriculum Name` to get updated to? you haven't provided any changes to it.   And in fact, you're updating the wrong table if you're looking to change `Curriculum Name` as it exists in your `Curriculum` table, and not your `GradeLevel` table.

Your update statement should look something more like this:

```
UPDATE Curriculum
SET 'Curriculum Name' = @curriculumName
WHERE curriculumId = @curriculumId
```

I don't see why you would want to update the Curriculum name based on a grade level id... it would be updating rows in your table numerous times with numerous potential different values.  So in the end, you wouldn't necessarily know what the name would be in the end.

Once your curriculum name is updated, any joins from grade -> curriculum on the correct column will show the newly updated curriculum name.

Honestly though, I'm not understanding your schema.  If both of those values are to be updated at the same time, having them as two separate tables seems off.  Are both of them always going to changed together? do they have a 1 to 1 relationship? They probably belong in the same table if that's the case.  Either that, or drop your PK on your grade table, and just make the curriculumId the primary key on both tables.  This way you'll have a 1to1 relationship, rather than a 1 to many.

Comment: if i use UPDATE Curriculum
SET 'Curriculum Name' = curriculumName
WHERE curriculumId = curriculumId

it will update my Curriculum table, 
i just need to get the Curriculum Name in my Grade Level Table when i add grade level to my Curriculum

Comment: @KennethChang can you try to reword your response?  I'm not understanding your meaning.

Comment: 1st table: Curriculum  = CurriculumID(PK) and CurriculumName----
2nd table: GradeLevel = GradeLevelID(PK), GradeLevelName, and CurriculumID(ForeignKey)----
Ex. Table1: CurriculumID = 1 & 2, CurriculumName = K-12 & K-13----
Table2: GradeLevelID = 1, GradeLevelName = Grade 2, CurriculumID = 1----
that was inserted, so next i need to update my Table2 CurriculumID rom 1 to 2 so the result will be 
Table2: GradeLevelID = 1, GradeLevelName = Grade 2, CurriculumID = 2----

Comment: @KennethChang that doesn't really help me understand your problem due to the format of comments.  Please update your question with all relevant information.  What data you currently have in both tables (sample), what you're trying to accomplish, and your expected resulting data.  I see you have made a "Result" section of your question, but as I stated in my answer, your schema doesn't really make sense for this sort of relationship.  At least not with the information I have about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe this answer looks more like a comment, but it requieres text formatting and is going to be long, so I decided to put it as an answer. Hope it doesn't cause any trouble*

Let me see if I get you well...

You have the next schema:

```
Curricuculum
--------------------------------
CurriculumID ( PK, Auto_Increment )
CurriculumName

GradeLevel
--------------------------------
GradeLevelID( PK, Auto_Increment )
GradeLevel
CurriculumID( Foreign Key )
```

And this data:

```
Curriculum
----------------------------------------
CurriculumId | CurriculumName
----------------------------------------
1            | K-12
2            | K-13

GradeLevel
----------------------------------------
GradeLevelId | GradeLevel | CurriculumId
----------------------------------------
1            | Grade 1    | 1
```

Doing this query:

```
SELECT g.GradeLevelId, g.GradeLevel, c.CurriculumName
FROM GradeLevel g
INNER JOIN Curriculum c
ON g.CurriculumId = c.CurriculumId
```

Returns this result:

```
------------------------------------------
GradeLevelId | GradeLevel | CurriculumName
------------------------------------------
1            | Grade 1    | K-12
```

Now you have in your code this update:

```
UPDATE GradeLevel set GradeLevel = @GradeLevel, CurriculumID = @CurriculumID where GradeLevelID = ' txtGradeLevelID.Text '
```

And you want to update `GradeLevel` so you'll have the data like this:

```
GradeLevel
----------------------------------------
GradeLevelId | GradeLevel | CurriculumId
----------------------------------------
1            | Grade 2    | 2
```

And running again the same query I put before would return now this result:

```
------------------------------------------
GradeLevelId | GradeLevel | CurriculumName
------------------------------------------
1            | Grade 2    | K-13
```

Now...
**is this what you really want?** you said in your question that you wanted to **update** `CurriculumName`, but you are never updating that field and your comments and answers tell me that you want only to **reference** to the record in `Curriculum` that has `CurriculumID = 2`. If this I've said is correct, your code so far looks like it would and should do it. So the few things I could tell you are:

- Put a breakpoint when you asign values to the query parameters and make sure they have the values you want (`txtGradeLevelID.text = "1"`, `txtGradeLevel.text = "Grade 2"` and `ComboBox1.Text = "2"`)
- Don't leave the `catch` empty; at least put a messagebox telling you what went wrong. Maybe there's an error and you'll never notice it.
- (Nothing to do really with your question per se but it's something to consider) If you're already using parameterized queries... why do you also have string concatenation? you can also use a parameter in your `WHERE` condition; there's no reason to mix both ways to run queries, and string concatenation is open to SQL injection and performance problems.

Now, if what I've said is not what you really want to achieve, please rephrase your question. Add to it any relevant info you have written in comments, and format it correctly (honestly, I find hard to believe your question hasn't been put on hold or even receive a single downvote)